# How to repair boost installation?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, build

I have removed all header files within the below path  due to numerous errors i was seeing

```
/usr/include/boost
```

The following is my install procedure...

```
cd boost_1_49_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$SRC_HEAD/third-party/build/boost_1_49_0
./b2 install
```

After a successful install i still do not see any include files within:
     /usr/include/boost! 
Can someone please advise, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as this suggests

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$SRC_HEAD/third-party/build/boost_1_49_0
```

it will install into `$SRC_HEAD/third-party/build/boost_1_49_0`, which is not `/usr/include/boost` obviously.

BUT I'm not suggesting you do this manually. Which distribution are you using? You should use the package manager, which comes with it to perform this task (reinstalling boost).

Comment: i am using ubunto, i tried a --includedir=/usr/include/boost which puts the header files there but now i am getting errors within my build such as /usr/include/boost/container/map.hpp:147:1: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>. This implies something did not copy correctly,

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install boost` or something, you should not install packages manually.

Comment: Why on earth don't you just build it with `--prefix=/usr` instead of trashing your system by manually removing and copying over files in system directories?

Comment: @JonathanWakely, building with `--prefix=/usr` actually *is* trashing your system already, why not use the package manager?